# ORC file and Sequence file reading same data for a query with where clause?

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

I have a table A with a column age in it. (table size is 74GB, Hive 0.13)

Now I created a table B with same data as of A, but in ORC file format and also included sort by age while creating B.

Now when I run the query:

*select count(id) from X where age=25;*

The data read from B table is same as size of B (I expected some pruning) and also the time taken in A ~ B.

Theoretically, because of predicate pushdown in ORC, a lot of data must have been skipped thus saving a lot of time. I suspect the indexes created in orc file are not getting read. I have tried almost everything. But nothing works. Please help with this.